# Making a Call From UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my project I am trying to make a phone call when the UI button is topped. Below is the implementation but when I run it from the Simulator or on my iPhone it doesn't work. How do I fix it?

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ListOfCarsTableViewCell
        let carsIndex = carsArray[indexPath.row]           
      cell.phoneButton.setTitle(carsIndex.dealer.phone.toPhoneNumber(), for: .normal)
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    @objc func callTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition){
            let phoneNumber = carsArray[indexPath.row].dealer.phone
            callNumber(phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
        }
        
    }
    
        func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {
            if let phoneCallURL = URL(string: "\(phoneNumber)") {
                let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
                if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL)) {
                    application.open(phoneCallURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
    cell.phoneButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.phoneButton.setTitle(carsIndex.dealer.phone.toPhoneNumber(), for: .normal)
    cell.phoneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

---

```
@objc func callTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let phoneNumber = carsArray[sender.tag].dealer.phone
    callNumber(phoneNumber: phoneNumber)
    
}
```

Also Don't forget to add `tel://` before phone number

Answer (score 2):

Add "tel://" on your url string

```
func callNumber(phoneNumber:String) {
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:]) { success in
                if success {
                    print("Making phone call")
                } else {
                    print("Something went wrong while making phone call")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Failed to make phone call")
        }
    }
```

Edit: I look that callTapped action is not connected with your phonebutton. Please add the following line at cellForRowAt function. It will work perfectly.

```
cell.phoneButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```